# Failed to build PIL on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion

Tags: python, macos, operating-system, python-imaging-library, osx-lion

I am tying to build PIL 1.1.7 on Mac OS X 10.7, I am getting this error:

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
--- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks
building '_imaging' extension
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Headers -IlibImaging -I/opt/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include -I/usr/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.6/_imaging.o
unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

I have the latest Xcode installed. gcc-4.0 does not exist but gcc-4.2 does. I don't know why it's trying to use gcc-4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using a 32-bit-only Python possibly one downloaded from python.org.  They are built with gcc-4.0 and for the i386 and ppc archs for compatibility with multiple OS X versions.  When building a C extension module, Python's Distutils will attempt to use the same compiler version and options that Python itself was build with.  Because gcc-4.0 and support for the ppc architecture are no longer included with Xcode 4 and OS X 10.7, you should not use the 32-bit-only builds on 10.7 if you need to build extension modules.  Either install a 64-bit/32-bit version of Python (2.7.2 and 3.2.2 are current from python.org) or use the Apple-supplied system Pythons in 10.7 (`/usr/bin/python` which defaults to 2.7.1).

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I was trying to use Python 2.6 from python.org because there is a problem with py2app + wxWidgets with the built-in version. I will have to try something different.